# Generic lambdas with statically sized arrays as arguments

Tags: c++, c++14, generic-lambda

Is the following generic (polymorphic) lambda legal C++14?

```
auto f = [](auto x[3]) {
    x[0];
    x[1];
    // etc.
};
```

GCC and Clang 4 accept the code, but Visual Studio 2017 does not. Is it legal?

```
error C3318: 'auto [3]': an array cannot have an element type that contains 'auto'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is illegal.

[[dcl.array]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1.sentence-1), emphasis mine:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
> D1 [ constant-expressionopt ] attribute-specifier-seqopt
> ```
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration `T D1` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”, then the type of the identifier of `D` is an array type; **if the type of the identifier of `D` contains the `auto` *type-specifier*, the program is ill-formed.**

Comment: Yeah, expect that for function definitions, this is not an array declaration, is it?

Comment: @StoryTeller It is an array declaration, even though it will be transformed into pointer type later.

Comment: You know, you have a point. If you try to specify an array with a negative size for the function parameter, GCC and Clang complain. So this seems like a non-standard extension for the case of `auto` alone.

Comment: This depends on whether you do this check directly on the generic lambda's *parameter-declaration-clause*, or instead only check it after it is transformed with invented template parameters. I also have a suspicion that this is intended to be allowed. +1 though.

Comment: @T.C. - Intended or not, it'd be nice if Clang and GCC were consistent. They reject an invalid declaration based on a negative size specifier, but accept another ostensibly invalid declaration.