# Is `auto`-array is a valid function parameter in C++20?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++20, auto

Please consider this sample C++20 program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

auto make_vector( auto v[2] ) { return std::vector{v[0], v[1]}; }

int main()
{
    int x[2] = {1, 2};
    auto v = make_vector( x );
    std::cout << v[0] << ' ' << v[1] << '\n';
}
```

Both GCC and Clang accept it (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jKT7GjMK6)

However the latest Visual Studio 2019 16.10.3 with `/std:c++latest` option rejects it:

> error C3318: 'auto [2]': an array cannot have an element type that contains 'auto'

Is it a bug or limitation of MSVC, or this code is not required to work in C++20?

Comment: [c++ - Generic lambdas with statically sized arrays as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902923/generic-lambdas-with-statically-sized-arrays-as-arguments/45903381)

Comment: @Pixelchemist - Thew rules *have changed* in C++20. And given the other question is explicitly C++14, a C++20 answer doesn't belong there. A dupe it is not.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I didn't say so nor did I (down/close) vote accordingly. I just provided this link for reference.

Comment: I think [cwg 2397](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2386r0.html#2397) (accepted last month) made this valid, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks like MSVC bug, MSVC accepts ```auto *``` parameter: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hcq43xsxb